# Does snapshot size is less than actual disk size even disk is full in google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have one disk with a size of 400GB which is full of data. when I take a snapshot of that disk on GCP, it shows only 280GB. is it normal?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is normal, from documentation: [Snapshots are incremental and automatically compressed, so you can create regular snapshots on a persistent disk faster and at a much lower cost than if you regularly created a full image of the disk.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#incremental-snapshots).

[image]

You can test the snapshot, [create a VM based on it](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/restore-and-delete-snapshots#restoresnapshottonew) and the VM must be working exactly as the one from which you create the snapshot.

Comment: Thanks for pointing GCP Documentions, it would be helpful for me to justify others.

Comment: Hello, if the information helps your please accept the answer, for other users could found it more easy

Comment: Okay, I did only click on "Up" arrow. but not on below "true" accept icon. now done.

Comment: Where do you see that they are compressed? My "Snapshot 1 (full snapshot)" is no where near what it should be. Thinking it would be compressed but unable to verify that in the documentation.